# jquery one field from two is empty, form submitting blocked

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, field

When the error message is displayed after both fields are not filled, and then i fill the second one (#phone), form is still blocked. Form is also blocked with the first send, even the second field is filled. Form always is submitted when the first field (#email) is not empty.

```
<form action="http://m.onet.pl" id="form" method="post">
<ul style="list-style:none">
    <li>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" /> 
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" /> 
    </li>
<li><button type="submit" name="sendad">Send form</button></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
    $("#form").submit(function(e){
        if(($('#email').val().length === 0 || $('#phone').val().length === 0)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#msg').html("One of two fields is reuired");
        } 
    });
```

What is wrong with the arguments?

http://jsfiddle.net/1do6332d/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/khahu9gy/

Simple mistake: use `&&` rather than `||`!

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
    if(($('#email').val().length === 0 && $('#phone').val().length === 0)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#msg').html("One of two fields is required");
    } 
});
```

Comment: No way! :)) Why i have not come across check other operator :)) Thank You mate... a lot time i lost because stupid operator :P

Comment: Yeap. Must wait 8 minutes from time when i tried accept first time :)
Thumbs up my questio so i can get some reputation poits.. without this i can thumbs up the topics :P